# package identifier or launch activity not found. Please check

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

package identifier or launch activity not found.
Please check D:\flutter\todoappnew\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml for errors.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.

anyone knows how to fix this, i tried flutter clean and flutter pub get

i tried flutter clean and flutter pub get but it wont working